# Transmitting files of 64k size through sockes fails

Tags: java, json, sockets, buffer

I am developing an application that uses java sockets between a server and client apps. I need to send files of size 64k from client to server through these sockets. When I locally run all the system (both, server and client) everything goes ok, but when I run the server and client in different machines it fails.

I am using JSON to process the file content, so the thrown exception in server is: "net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError". However the problem is not JSON, is the size of the file. When I send files with a size lesser than 8k everything goes ok, but bigger sizes truncates the sent information, so it throws a JSONTokener.syntaxError when server tries to interpret truncated received information.

I am defining a socket buffer of 64k as following (I am using NIO API):

```
SocketChannel sc;
private static final int BUFFER _SIZE = (int)Math.pow(2, 16);
.....
sc.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(  BUFFER_SIZE );
sc.socket().setSendBufferSize( BUFFER_SIZE );
```

What do I need to do to enlarge the network package size when I run my system in a remote mode? Do you have any idea which is the problem?
Thank you very much in advance.

Oscar

Comment: Sounds like your reading code is probably broken. Don't try to rely on everything going in a single packet, which is probably what you're hoping for at the moment... if this is TCP, it's a *stream* protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer sizes are typically over 64K so you could be actually shrinking them.

The MTU for TCP packets is typically 1.5 KB and changing this is highly unlikely to help you.  In any case, 9000 bytes is the most I have ever seen it set to.

The problem you have could be in the way you are writing the data, but I suspect its in the way you are reading the data.  It a common mistake to assume you will receive the same size of data you sent or that you will receive it all at once.

Streams do not "know" what size of data you wrote and you don't know when all the data sent has been received unless you have a protocol which includes the length.